# Native Linux app to edit Win32 PE like ResHacker

Tags: linux, winapi, portable-executable

I want to run a auto modify .dll service, users submit a specific .dll, I modify it on the server, then user can download modified version of the .dll. Are there any native Linux app that provide common Win32 PE modification capabilities like Icons, Strings, Accelerators, Dialogues, etc. which at least provide a commandline or scripting API ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`i586-mingw32msvc-windres`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/binutils/windres.html) as a part of the mingw package.

```
NAME
       windres - manipulate Windows resources.
```

Command line only, but you can check the source as binutils are free (as in speech).

Comment: Thank you LiraNuna, it's very helpful.

But I have problem compile modified .rc back to .dll, I use the commandline 

    windres test.dll test.rc

got the desired test.rc, I modified something, then

    windres test.rc test.dll

The test.dll is corrupted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a windows developer so I have no idea how to actually use this, I just know it exists :)