# C library to read EXE version from Linux?

Tags: c, windows, linux, portable-executable

Is there a library I can use in Linux that will return the properties of a Windows EXE file that are listed in Explorer's Version tab? These are fields like Product Name, Product Version, Description, etc.

For my project, the EXE file can be only read from memory, not from a file. I would like to avoid writing the EXE file to disk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291570/native-linux-app-to-edit-win32-pe-like-reshacker?rq=1

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the restriction of the EXE file can be only read from memory.  Nor do I understand the comment that you would like to avoid writing the EXE file to disk.  The various EXE properties you describe are resources, strings, stored in the resource section of an EXE or DLL.  So the basic mechanics are to read the EXE or DLL file looking for the resource section and then parse through the resource section looking for the specific version, etc. resources that you want and display them.

Comment: Are you poking a running executable on another machine (from Linux to Windows), maybe through a firewire DMA access ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The version of the file is in the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct, but you have to find it into the executable data. There are two ways of doing what you want:

1. Search for the VERSION_INFO signature in the file and read the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct  directly.
2. Find the `.rsrc` section, parse the resource tree, find the `RT_VERSION` resource, parse it and extract the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` data.

The first one is easier, but susceptible to find the signature by chance in the wrong place. Moreover, the other data you ask for (product name, description, etc.) are not in this structure, so I'll try to explain how to obtain the data the hard way.

The PE format is a bit convoluted so I'm pasting the code piece by piece, with comments, and with minimum error checking. I'll write a simple function that dumps the data to the standard output. Writing it as a proper function is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Note that I will be using offsets in the buffer instead of mapping the structs directly to avoid portability problems related to the alignment or padding of the struct fields. Anyway, I've annotated the type of the structs used (see include file winnt.h for details).

First a few useful declarations, they should be self-explanatory:

```
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef uint16_t WORD;
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

#define READ_BYTE(p) (((unsigned char*)(p))[0])
#define READ_WORD(p) ((((unsigned char*)(p))[0]) | ((((unsigned char*)(p))[1]) << 8))
#define READ_DWORD(p) ((((unsigned char*)(p))[0]) | ((((unsigned char*)(p))[1]) << 8) | \
    ((((unsigned char*)(p))[2]) << 16) | ((((unsigned char*)(p))[3]) << 24))

#define PAD(x) (((x) + 3) & 0xFFFFFFFC)
```

Then a function that finds the Version resource in the executable image (no size checks).

```
const char *FindVersion(const char *buf)
{
```

The first structure in the EXE is the MZ header (for compatibility with MS-DOS).

```
    //buf is a IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
    if (READ_WORD(buf) != 0x5A4D) //MZ signature
        return NULL;
```

The only field interesting in the MZ header is the offset of the PE header. The PE header is the real thing.

```
    //pe is a IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32
    const char *pe = buf + READ_DWORD(buf + 0x3C);
    if (READ_WORD(pe) != 0x4550) //PE signature
        return NULL;
```

Actually, the PE header is quite boring, we want the COFF header, that have all the symbolic data.

```
    //coff is a IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
    const char *coff = pe + 4;
```

We just need the following fields from this one.

```
    WORD numSections = READ_WORD(coff + 2);
    WORD optHeaderSize = READ_WORD(coff + 16);
    if (numSections == 0 || optHeaderSize == 0)
        return NULL;
```

The optional header is actually mandatory in an EXE and it is just after the COFF. The magic is different for 32 and 64 bits Windows. I'm assuming 32 bits from here on.

```
    //optHeader is a IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32
    const char *optHeader = coff + 20;
    if (READ_WORD(optHeader) != 0x10b) //Optional header magic (32 bits)
        return NULL;
```

Here comes the interesting part: we want to find the resources section. It has two parts: 1. the section data, 2. the section metadata.

The data location is in a table at the end of the optional header, and each section has a well known index in this table. Resource section is in index 2, so we obtain the virtual address (VA) of the resource section with:

```
    //dataDir is an array of IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
    const char *dataDir = optHeader + 96;
    DWORD vaRes = READ_DWORD(dataDir + 8*2);

    //secTable is an array of IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER
    const char *secTable = optHeader + optHeaderSize;
```

To get the section metadata we need to iterate the section table looking for a section named `.rsrc`.

```
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numSections; ++i)
    {
        //sec is a IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*
        const char *sec = secTable + 40*i;
        char secName[9];
        memcpy(secName, sec, 8);
        secName[8] = 0;

        if (strcmp(secName, ".rsrc") != 0)
            continue;
```

The section struct has two relevant members: the VA of the section and the offset of the section into the file (also the size of the section, but I'm not checking it!):

```
        DWORD vaSec = READ_DWORD(sec + 12);
        const char *raw = buf + READ_DWORD(sec + 20);
```

Now the offset in the file that correspond to the `vaRes` VA we got before is easy.

```
        const char *resSec = raw + (vaRes - vaSec);
```

This is a pointer to the resource data. All the individual resources are set up in the form of a tree, with 3 levels: 1) type of resource, 2) identifier of resource, 3) language of resource. For the version we will get the very first one of the correct type.

First, we have a resource directory (for the type of resource), we get the number of entries in the directory, both named and unnamed and iterate:

```
        WORD numNamed = READ_WORD(resSec + 12);
        WORD numId = READ_WORD(resSec + 14);

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < numNamed + numId; ++j)
        {
```

For each resource entry we get the type of the resource and discard it if it is not the RT_VERSION constant (16).

```
            //resSec is a IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY followed by an array
            // of IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY
            const char *res = resSec + 16 + 8 * j;
            DWORD name = READ_DWORD(res);
            if (name != 16) //RT_VERSION
                continue;
```

If it is a RT_VERSION we get to the next resource directory in the tree:

```
            DWORD offs = READ_DWORD(res + 4);
            if ((offs & 0x80000000) == 0) //is a dir resource?
                return NULL;
            //verDir is another IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY and 
            // IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY array
            const char *verDir = resSec + (offs & 0x7FFFFFFF);
```

And go on to the next directory level, we don't care about the id. of this one:

```
            numNamed = READ_WORD(verDir + 12);
            numId = READ_WORD(verDir + 14);
            if (numNamed == 0 && numId == 0)
                return NULL;
            res = verDir + 16;
            offs = READ_DWORD(res + 4);
            if ((offs & 0x80000000) == 0) //is a dir resource?
                return NULL;
```

The third level has the language of the resource. We don't care either, so just grab the first one:

```
            //and yet another IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY, etc.
            verDir = resSec + (offs & 0x7FFFFFFF);                    
            numNamed = READ_WORD(verDir + 12);
            numId = READ_WORD(verDir + 14);
            if (numNamed == 0 && numId == 0)
                return NULL;
            res = verDir + 16;
            offs = READ_DWORD(res + 4);
            if ((offs & 0x80000000) != 0) //is a dir resource?
                return NULL;
            verDir = resSec + offs;
```

And we get to the real resource, well, actually a struct that contains the location and size of the real resource, but we don't care about the size.

```
            DWORD verVa = READ_DWORD(verDir);
```

That's the VA of the version resouce, that is converted into a pointer easily.

```
            const char *verPtr = raw + (verVa - vaSec);
            return verPtr;
```

And done! If not found return `NULL`.

```
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Now that the version resource is found, we have to parse it. It is actually a tree (what else) of pairs "name" / "value". Some values are well known and that's what you are looking for, just do some test and you will find out which ones.

**NOTE**: All strings are stored in UNICODE (UTF-16) but my sample code does the dumb conversion into ASCII. Also, no checks for overflow.

The function takes the pointer to the version resource and the offset into this memory (0 for starters) and returns the number of bytes analyzed.

```
int PrintVersion(const char *version, int offs)
{
```

First of all the offset have to be a multiple of 4.

```
    offs = PAD(offs);
```

Then we get the properties of the version tree node.

```
    WORD len    = READ_WORD(version + offs);
    offs += 2;
    WORD valLen = READ_WORD(version + offs);
    offs += 2;
    WORD type   = READ_WORD(version + offs);
    offs += 2;
```

The name of the node is a Unicode zero-terminated string.

```
    char info[200];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        WORD c = READ_WORD(version + offs);
        offs += 2;

        info[i] = c;
        if (!c)
            break;
    }
```

More padding, if neccesary:

```
    offs = PAD(offs);
```

If `type` is not 0, then it is a string version data.

```
    if (type != 0) //TEXT
    {
        char value[200];
        for (i=0; i < valLen; ++i)
        {
            WORD c = READ_WORD(version + offs);
            offs += 2;
            value[i] = c;
        }
        value[i] = 0;
        printf("info <%s>: <%s>\n", info, value);
    }
```

Else, if the name is `VS_VERSION_INFO` then it is a `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct. Else it is binary data.

```
    else
    {
        if (strcmp(info, "VS_VERSION_INFO") == 0)
        {
```

I'm just printing the version of the file and product, but you can find the other fields of this struct easily. Beware of the *mixed endian* order.

```
            //fixed is a VS_FIXEDFILEINFO
            const char *fixed = version + offs;
            WORD fileA = READ_WORD(fixed + 10);
            WORD fileB = READ_WORD(fixed + 8);
            WORD fileC = READ_WORD(fixed + 14);
            WORD fileD = READ_WORD(fixed + 12);
            WORD prodA = READ_WORD(fixed + 18);
            WORD prodB = READ_WORD(fixed + 16);
            WORD prodC = READ_WORD(fixed + 22);
            WORD prodD = READ_WORD(fixed + 20);
            printf("\tFile: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", fileA, fileB, fileC, fileD);
            printf("\tProd: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", prodA, prodB, prodC, prodD);
        }
        offs += valLen;
    }
```

Now do the recursive call to print the full tree.

```
    while (offs < len)
        offs = PrintVersion(version, offs);
```

And some more padding before returning.

```
    return PAD(offs);
}
```

Finally, as a bonus, a `main` function.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(argv[1], &st) < 0)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *buf = malloc(st.st_size);

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!f)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    fread(buf, 1, st.st_size, f);
    fclose(f);

    const char *version = FindVersion(buf);
    if (!version)
        printf("No version\n");
    else
        PrintVersion(version, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tested it with a few random EXEs and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Awesome answer! This link is going to be my reply when anyone asks "How good stackoverflow is?"

Comment: I created a gist combining all the C listings into a single C source code file. I have verified it compiles and works. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/djhaskin987/d1860a7d98193913bcfa

Comment: It would be better if you can give some reference too.

Answer (score 3):

I know `pev` is a tool on Ubuntu that allows you to see this information, along with a lot of other PE header info. I also know it's written in C. [Maybe you'll want to have a look at it](http://pev.sourceforge.net/). A bit from its [history section](http://pev.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/en_us/ch01.html) in the docs:

> pev has born in 2010 from a simple need: a program to find out the
>   version (File Version) of a PE32 file and that could be run in Linux.
>   This version number is stored in Resources (.rsrc) section but at the
>   time we've decided to simply search for the string in the whole
>   binary, without any optimization.
>
> Later on we've decided to parse the PE32 file until reach .rsrc
>   section and get the File Version field. In order to do that, we
>   realized we must parse the entire file and we thought if we could
>   print out all the fields and values as well...
>
> Until version 0.40, pev was an unique program for parse the PE headers
>   and sections (now readpe is responsible for this). In version 0.50 we
>   focused on malware analysis and splitted pev into various programs
>   beyond a library, called libpe. Currently all pev programs use libpe.

Answer (score 1):

Install winelib http://www.winehq.org/docs/winelib-guide/index
This is port of MS Windows API to others systems, including linux.

Then use MS Windows API. Like `GetFileVersionInfo` 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx

Or any other functions.

I never did it, but I would start with these findings.

Regarding exe file in memory constraint, can you copy it to RAM disk?

Comment: Does this solution require that WINE be installed on the machine on which the application is being used?  Is winelib a static library or has a static library version so that an executable could be ported to other Linux machines without installing WINE on that machine?  Is this independent of Linux distro?

Comment: @RichardChambers AFAIK application compiled with winelib requires  Wine to run.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patch for code to support PE32+. Tested on some files and seems to work.

```
//optHeader is a IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32
const char *optHeader = coff + 20;
WORD magic = READ_WORD(optHeader);
if (magic != 0x10b && magic != 0x20b)
    return NULL;

//dataDir is an array of IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
const char *dataDir = optHeader + (magic==0x10b ? 96: 112);
DWORD vaRes = READ_DWORD(dataDir + 8*2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in the Tcl language to parse through a .exe file to retrieve the version information.

[Reading version information from Win32 executables](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8949).

This [web page describes the .exe header format](http://www.winhex.com/winhex/kb/ff/NE_EXE.txt).  I am not sure of the date of this information or whether it applies to more recent versions of Windows or not.  However it is a starting place.