# Can I find an offset of a resource in an EXE file with C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, exe

I'm writing a custom module that checks EXE files for consistency (which is not a part of this question.) For that I need to know an offset of a certain resource in the EXE file to calculate the size of the EXE file body that I need to check.

I came up with the following code to get an offset of the `IDR_HTML_DLG` resource in the `strExeFilePath` file:

```
int ncbOffsetInBytes = 0;
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(strExeFilePath);
if(hModule)
{
    HRSRC hRes = ::FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_HTML_DLG), RT_HTML);
    if(hRes)
    {
        long szLength = ::SizeofResource(hModule, hRes);
        HGLOBAL hGlobal = ::LoadResource(hModule, hRes);
        if(szLength && hGlobal)
        {
            BYTE* pData = (BYTE*)LockResource(hGlobal);
            DWORD dwLast = (DWORD)(pData + szLength);
            DWORD dwFirst = (DWORD)hModule;

            ncbOffsetInBytes = dwLast - dwFirst;
        }
    }

    ::FreeLibrary(hModule);
    hModule = NULL;
}
```

But the result in `ncbOffsetInBytes` turns out larger than the EXE file itself. Any idea how to correct it?

Comment: I think that the problem is that the module is not mapped into memory in a single block, but in several separated pieces: the `.text` here, the `.data` there, the `.rsrc` over there... And some parts of the EXE are probably not even loaded at all!

Comment: If you can post a piece of code that simply defines a resource in a DLL I can see if I can help figure it out?

Comment: Thanks. I see @rodrigo point. You are probably right and I am not on the right track here...

Comment: why don't you simply delve into the headers

Answer (score 2):

As @rodrigo points out, when a PE file is loaded into memory each of the relevant sections will be loaded into different memory sections, with padding between each section, and the offsets of sections, as well as the size of the module itself, will be different that the PE file on disk. There is some information on how this works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx).

As I see it there are two ways you could do what you're trying to do.. You either need to take into account the size of the PE in memory and base your calculations on that - I believe the `SizeOfImage` member of [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives the image size as loaded into memory. The other option would be to continue to use the size of the PE file on disk, in which case you could load the PE file into memory as a data file (rather than using `LoadLibrary`) and work in it from there. In this case, if you need to retrieve the offset of resources etc from the file you will probably need to manually parse and crawl the PE file structure - there is an excellent reference for this structure [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx).

Comment: @c00000fd: Or you can read this other [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396665/c-library-to-read-exe-version-from-linux/12486703#12486703). It is relevant to the `RT_VERSION`, but your code could be quite similar.