# How to change Eclipse RCP product exe properties

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I am using Maven with Tycho plugin to materialize the Eclipse RCP product. What I need is when I right-click the product exe file and choose properties I need some relevant information onthe Details tab (File Description, Product Name, Product Version...).

Now I have found so far, that this could be achieved with .rc file with VERSIONINFO statement
(see [Comment 10 at this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294827#c10)). I also found in [tycho-user mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg04226.html) that rc file CAN be included in Tycho build to achieve the desired behavior. Nontheless I was unable to find out where to put the rc file, or how to name it or where to set its location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misreading the bugzilla discussion, as that is only possible by self-compiling the eclipse launcher source (with a modified rc file).

However, there is an alternative: You can patch the launcher executable manually (using any kind of resource editor) and then put it into your product as [root file](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_rootfiles.htm). This works with tycho, I use that approach. The drawback is of course that this executable will not be updated, if you change branding details in the product definition file.

Alternatively to a root file you could also overwrite the launcher executable during an installation creation (outside of Eclipse). E.g. we create an NSIS installer around an RCP app and can also modify it there.

Comment: Marked as correct answer, as I managed to update the version info using resource editor and assuming there really is no other way to do it during RCP build time.

Do you think there is any chance the executable can be updated after the build using Maven (p.e. using antrun plugin and calling some command line resource editor) but on Linux? I am pretty sure it could be achieved on Windows, unfortunately my build machine runs Linux.

Comment: I have never tried. https://code.google.com/p/rescle/ is unfortunately windows only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291570/native-linux-app-to-edit-win32-pe-like-reshacker looks like what you want. Those can also be found googling "linux edit pe file" or "linux edit pe header".